Problem in sympy with limit of an expression at infinity
The following code give the answer : nan instead of -pi/4
Could you tell me where the problem is ?
import sympy as sp  # sympy.org

sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

x= sp.Symbol('x', real=True) 
                                         
expr=sp.atan((1-x)/(x+3))

sp.pprint(sp.limit(expr,x,-sp.oo)) 


This code calculates the limit for x tending to minus infinity of the expression atan((1-x)/(x+3))
When you run the code, the result is nan (not a number) when it should be -pi/4.
Why does this code give an incorrect result ?

SymPy 1.13.3 is able to compute the limit:
sp.limit(expr,x,-sp.oo)
# -π 
# ───
#  4 

You are probably using an older version of sympy. You can checkout your version by running:
import sympy as sp;print(sp.__version__)


Thanks for the reply, it works fine, but I first had to update my environment (Thonny) to be able to load the latest version of sympy.
